# Silverlight object persistence

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, browser

Is it possible to have the same Silverlight object host persist in memory as the user traverses our site?  I'm interested in having my Silverlight objects stick around from page to page.

Using IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

Typically to achieve this you make the decision that the Silverlight application **is** your site (or at least a complete segment of your site) and use Silverlight Navigation framework to allow the user to navigate from "page to page" within the application.  Where "page" refers to various Xaml pages within a single Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could store the object in JSON or XML in the IsolatedStorage for the Site (not the application) and use the built in serialization methods to work with the object. Then just check for its existence for each app that is loaded.